# How can I inject a common code in components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For multiple React component , I want to inject a common code to the life cycle of React.
Is there something good way?

```
var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {

    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
      //inject common code
    },...

var ComponentB = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {

    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
      //inject common code
    },...
```

Comment: Check out [this link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understanding-react-higher-order-components-by-example-95e8c47c8006)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though higher order component approach suggested by @jzm is [better](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.l9h6cdskj), you could also use mixins:

```
var myMixin = {
      componentWillMount: function(){
         //common code
      },
      componentDidUpdate: function(){
        //common code
      }
};
var ComponentA = React.createClass({
   mixin: [myMixin]
});
var ComponentB = React.createClass({
   mixin: [myMixin]
})
```

Comment: In fact, it did not work @jzm approach , I was also resolved in mixin.
mixin looks useful.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'I was also resolved in mixin'?

Comment: @izuchy Mixins will not be supported in react in the future. So they are not the right way to approach this. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

Comment: @jzm Thank you very much. Mixin is not so much recommended...Oh.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean just sharing functions across multiple components? If so, you can just keep them in a separate file and import them where ever you need to:

```
// common js

function hello() {
  console.log('hello');
}

module.exports = hello;

// your component
var hello = require('./common');

var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
      hello();
    },//...
```

http://www.webpackbin.com/Nk80m1x_W

---

Another thing you can do is create a wrapper (higher order) component:

```
var WrapperComponent = React.createClass({
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
     // code you want to inject.
  },
  render: function () {
    return(<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
  }
});
```

then whenever you need to use a component with that lifecycle, you can do this in jsx:

```
<WrapperComponent>
   <ComponentA />
</WrapperComponent>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But since the number of components is large, I think in a way you know , such as to override the life cycle ?